# JQuery animate to scroll to top of div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a hidden div, .model-detail-panel that is revealed when clicking .span.

```
$('[class*="span"]').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().next('.model-detail-panel').slideToggle()
    });
```

I want to incorporate .animate() into this code to scroll the screen so that the top of the revealed div is at the top of the window.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [Position](http://api.jquery.com/position/), like this:

```
$("body, html").animate({
    scrollTop: $(".model-detail-panel").position().top
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this does not do anything. In your code is .top supposed to be the top of .model-detail-panel?

Comment: Yes, it is. Try to console.log that value.

Comment: running console.log results in the window object being returned. Ideally I want the .model-detail-panel to be the result?

Comment: @webworker Try yhis: console.log($(".model-detail-panel").position().top);

Answer (score 4):

Slightly changing the code suggested by @michele-bertoli to

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".model-detail-panel").offset().top
            }, 500);
```

Has worked for me..

Thanks to those who posted..